# How to give a Dynamic SQL script in C# windows form?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am developing an application for my project using C# windows form. I have a dynamic SQL script, please refer the below script:

I need to give this Dynamic SQL script in C# : (command part)

```
`command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

command.CommandText =???`
```

Please help me out in this. If I give normally I am getting Exception error in @SQL part.
`

```
Declare @Sql nvarchar(max)


 Set @Sql ='CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].geoid (@InStr VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @TempTable TABLE
(id int not null)
AS
BEGIN

SET @InStr = @InStr + '',''
DECLARE @SP INT
DECLARE @VALUE VARCHAR(1000)
WHILE PATINDEX(''%,%'', @INSTR ) <> 0---(1,2,3,4,5,)

BEGIN

SELECT @SP = PATINDEX(''%,%'',@INSTR)
SELECT @VALUE = LEFT(@INSTR , @SP - 1)--=1
SELECT @INSTR = STUFF(@INSTR, 1, @SP, '''')--(2,3,4,5)
INSERT INTO @TempTable(id) VALUES (@VALUE)
END
RETURN
END
'
declare @xyz varchar(200)

Exec (@sql)
```

`

Comment: *"I am getting Exception error in @SQL part."* And the error message is ... ?

Comment: SQL exception was Unhandled occured in System.data.dll. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'set'

Comment: Cannot debug c# code that you do not post.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating the function using command text

You can do something like below for dynamic query

```
public void Test()
    {
        string commandText = "Select CatId From tbl_T2H_Category Where Category IN (@cat_1,@cat_2 @cat_3)";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
        command.Parameters.Add("@cat1", SqlDbType.Varchar);
        command.Parameters["@cat1"].Value = "category1";
        command.Parameters.Add("@cat2", SqlDbType.Varchar);
        command.Parameters["@cat2"].Value = "category2";
        command.Parameters.Add("@cat3", SqlDbType.Varchar);
        command.Parameters["@cat3"].Value = "category3";
    }
```

Comment: I need to give the above SQL script in C# code. Can you please help me.